# What are the advantages of "annotations" in Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've been using Symfony for a while and I see that Doctrine, the preferred way to handle MySQL databases, makes use of *annotations* (see [annotations reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html)). My question is: why do the exist? I find them hard to read and to debug. What is the advantage of such a programming language?

Comment: Among other things, it's a way of simulating macros in PHP

Comment: They exist so you, as a programmer, can see right away how everything is "glued" together or will be parsed later on. (eg. if you declare a property as integer, it'll always be an integer and cause an Exception if you throw in an string for example)
The downside is, that the php files with annotation have to be parsed beforehand, that can and will cause a a few seconds before "anything" really happens. Because "the background" has to read the annotations and adapt to it, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance of all three drivers are the same, because they are cached after the first read. There is very little objective advantage, if any, the only one I can think of is with XML you can statically validate your mapping (with an XSD), which is not possible with annotations, or YML, or the "native PHP" implementation.

With that said, some people prefer annotations, because it keeps the mapping configuration closer to the entities, instead of placing them in a separate file. When you have to change the entity, it's easier to change the mapping, because you don't have to look in a separate file. That's all.